# PrestaShop - Update price by reference on php

Tags: php, json, prestashop

I'm getting a daily JSON with prices that I must update in the website. I'm able to read the json with php properly, but I have no clue on how to update the price of the products. I have tried modifying the DB directly but I get no success. The objective is to find every product that has a specific reference (normally one product, but maybe there are some duplicates), and then change the price. I read these two data from the JSON, the reference and the price. So far, I created a whole new php file and 'm trying:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php');
```

```
foreach ($json_datos as $articulo){
    $cod_articulo = $articulo["Cod_Articulo"]; //this comes from the previously read json
    $precio_articulo = $articulo["PVP"]; //this comes from the previously read json

    $query = "UPDATE `"._DB_PREFIX_."product` prod SET price=".$precio_articulo." WHERE prod.reference=".$cod_articulo.";";
    Db::getInstance()->Execute($query);
}
```

This code gives no error, neither any change.

Comment: You should not try and work “around” such a system in the first place, by manipulating stuff in the database directly. This should use the shop system’s own methods to locate and then update these products.

Comment: I know this, but I believe is going to be even more difficult to me to try to get and understand the guts of Prestashop. Actually the purpose is to be able to execute the PHP every 24 hours to read the most recent json and update the prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Product object to implement your goal.

```
foreach ($json_datos as $articulo) {
    $cod_articulo = $articulo["Cod_Articulo"];
    $precio_articulo = $articulo["PVP"];

    $product = new Product(Product::getIdByReference($cod_articulo));
    $product->price = $precio_articulo;
    $product->update();
}
```

this way is much safer and stable

**UPD:**
for versions lower 1.7.6 you need to define your own method

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');

function getIdByReference($reference)
{
    if (empty($reference)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (!Validate::isReference($reference)) {
        return 0;
    }

    $query = new DbQuery();
    $query->select('p.id_product');
    $query->from('product', 'p');
    $query->where('p.reference = \'' . pSQL($reference) . '\'');

    return Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
}

foreach ($json_datos as $articulo) {
    $cod_articulo = $articulo["Cod_Articulo"];
    $precio_articulo = $articulo["PVP"];

    $product = new Product(getIdByReference($cod_articulo));
    $product->price = $precio_articulo;
    $product->update();
}
```

but in this case, it loses sense a bit. But it is still safer to update a price within a product object

Comment: I'm trying to run this from "PostMan" to see if it works, but I just get a 500 error. I don't know if it happens because I'm trying to access the php from outside the server.

Comment: Enable Debug mode and check log files to get an error report

Comment: One question. This file is solely created with the purpose of being executed by a cron job. If this is the case, Do this code work if its executed outside prestashop website environment? It is placed inside the web folder but I don't actually understand how this code works.
(I need it to be executed every 24 hours).

Comment: You need to include at least these files include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php'); include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php'); to get access to your prestashop environment. Then check if the script is executable and set up your cronjob to run it

Comment: But the best way would be to create a simple module that would do the job for you. There is a lot of information how to build it in the internet

Comment: I have these two files included, but php throws a 500 error, in the other hand, If I do a standard mysql query, it runs successfully. This is why I asked. 
I  have it this way:
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php'); (with double underline before and after "FILE".)

Comment: I checked it out one more time and it works even without including init.php file. I just put my script(test.php) into the root directory and run it within URL myRootUrl/test.php

Comment: It throws "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getIdByReference" of class "Product".

I have :
 $product = new Product(Product::getIdByReference($cod_articulo));
    $product->price = $precio_articulo;
    $product->update();

Comment: Ok, what version of Prestashop do you have?

Comment: I'm using 1.7.4.2. Not that old I believe.

Comment: Now I understood, this method "getIdByReference" added in version 1.7.6. So in your case, it won't work. You can add this method directly to your script before $product definition. I'll update the answer

Comment: Can I create this method in product class and use it from anywhere? (if yes, please, explain how, I'm not very confident on how Prestashop works).

Comment: Basically speaking you can, but don't forget about it if you gonna update your core to lower then 1.7.6 version (classes/Product.php and make your method public static). Also, you can override Product class and add this method there, create Product.php file in override/classes/ folder, extend ProductCore in the class definition and  put your method inside the new class. After that don't forget to remove var/cache/dev(or prod)/class_index.php and class_stub.php files. This way you should not bother about updates

Comment: I think this should do it. I'm trying to read now a file in a parent directory with scandir, and using "../../folder" but for some reason it is not finding it. This is not related to the issue though. I thank you for all your help @Alexander Grosul

Comment: Actually, it is throwing this errors:
La propiedad Product->price no es válida

in ObjectModel.php line 954
at ObjectModelCore->validateFields()
in ObjectModel.php line 272
at ObjectModelCore->getFields()
in ObjectModel.php line 694
at ObjectModelCore->update(false)
in Product.php line 622
at ProductCore->update()
in TisaPrice.php line 16

Comment: What type of value do you try to set?

Comment: just price. In the tables, it appears as decimal value, I don't know if I have to parse this value to double or something?

Comment: Probably you get a string value, try to put (float) before a price like (float)$articulo["PVP"]. Or add verification before, like if Validate::isPrice((float)$articulo["PVP"]); then commit changes

Comment: The prices (field PVP) are like  "888,88". I'm afraid that the comma symbol is not parsed correctly, when I do a (float) it shows just "888".

Comment: Replace comma if you sure that the price will be always that format

Comment: Well, used: `(float)str_replace(",",".",$precio_articulo);`
Becomes this huge mess:
[link](https://pastebin.com/Q2FHACVH)

Comment: But, somehow, you have id_product = 0

Comment: I'll check tomorrow as I'm leaving now. Will keep you informed. Thanks for everything!

Comment: My mistake is that I was trying to update an non-existent code. It is working. Thanks a lot!